# set room resource in Calendar App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

My G Suite has room resources set and I  can add resources to an event manually but not pro grammatically.  I cannot find any reference in the documentation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the CalendarApp service this is quite straightforward, rooms have IDs that are very similar to email adresses, you have to invite these ressources just as you would invite guests.
It comes as optional parameter in the [createEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)) method in the form of an array of email adresses.

You will find these adresses in the agenda of each of these rooms (properties).